Some に vs. で exceptions (?) for places
I know Duolingo is not a reliable source for Japanese study, but I've recently encountered a few cases of particle usage there. If these are just errors on their part, I would still like your confirmation
I have studied several similar questions already asked here but haven't found anything quite close to what I'm asking about, so I'll just post all three here (one of them is easy, but I'll leave it in for completeness if someone else in the future has a similar "brain glitch")
I've copied them precisely as they were on Duolingo (I made screenshots; the only difference is that I used kanji instead of kana in some cases and used Arabic numbers instead of kanji, 二千十四, in the third one since in my experience kanji is almost never used for years in everyday writing)

十二月にコミュニティセンターでパフォーマンスがあります。
(I expected に instead of で here, though I now suspect that で here might be OK since a performance can be anywhere and does not require a place... but using で with ある feels unusual in itself)

イタリアに留学しました。
(I expected で here, but maybe に is more appropriate since you need a place to study at, at least in this case where it's important that it's abroad)

２０１４年に卒業しました。
(I know it's obvious, but my brain froze for a few seconds when I first saw this since I was already focused on the whole に/で thing, and the verb is an action verb, not a state one... but this is not the case for this difference at all since the particle is used with the year, not the place — there is no place mentioned at all)



I found another verb that takes に and not で although I expected it: 浮かぶ.  On second thought, especially now that I'm getting used to it, It makes sense though as it does not require the object to do anything I guess (compared to actually swimming): you just need to be buoyant enough, and you'll stay afloat


パフォーマンス is an event that takes place, not a visible object that exists. Generally, when the subject is an event, you need to say [place] + で + [event] + がある. In English, "There is a ～" works for both cases, but in Japanese, you need to choose the correct particle depending on the type of the subject.

This に is a destination marker, and 留学する is actually a movement verb. See rk03's answer.

2014年 is not a place but a time expression, and you need to use に with time. Fortunately, the particle usage is pretty consistent in Japanese:

2014年に = in 2014
火曜日に = on Tuesday
8時に = at 8 o'clock
朝に = in the morning
夜に = at night
過去に = in the past




Sorry for partial answer, but I would like to point out that your 2nd point is somewhat specific to the verb 留学する. Although often translated as “to study abroad”, its usage is closer to “to go abroad to learn/study”: the place they learn/study is typically marked by the particle に or へ as if it were destination, and it is an intransitive verb (i.e. does not take the particle を to indicate what they learn/study).
